# Creating a reverse ordered array

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to create an array and display it reverse or descending order. It currently displays a list of numbers but sometimes it does not follow the correct descending order. I believe the issues is in the if statement in between the two for loops, each time I am comparing a random number between 1-101 with the first number in your array. Instead of doing it that way, How can I compare the numbers in the array with each other? Or any suggestion in proving my reverse order array generator?

**CODE**

```
namespace reverseArray
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        long operations = 0;
        int size;
        int max;
        int[] createArray;
        int[] sortArray;
        int[] copyArray;

public void ReverseOrder()
        {
            size = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSize.Text);
            max = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMax.Text);
            createArray = new int[size];
            copyArray = new int[size];
            sortArray = new int[size];

            createArray[size - 1] = 1;

            for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                createArray[i - 1] = createArray[i] + r.Next(1, max);
            }

            for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (r.Next(1, 101) < createArray[0])
                {
                    for (int x = size - 1; x > 0; x--)
                    {
                        createArray[x] = r.Next(1, createArray[0]);
                    }
                }
            }

        }


private void buttonCreateArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

ReverseOrder();

}

}

}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the LINQ Reverse, OrderBy, or OrderByDescending functions? Your question is really confusing. `r.Next` looks like a `Random` instance. What on earth are you doing in the loops?

Comment: Of the three arrays you have defined (`createArray`, `copyArray` and `sortArray`), which is supposed to be the array of `int`s in descending order?

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe it is the `createArray`

Comment: @charliecodex23 If `createArray` is the array of `int`s in descending order, what is the original array that you created initially?

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe. Clarification: the `createArray` is the original array created initially. Then the for loops arranges(or tries to) the array in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LINQ`

```
using System.Linq;

namespace reverseArray
{
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            long operations = 0;
            int size;
            int max;
            int[] createArray;
            int[] orderedArray;
            int[] orderedByDescendingArray;    

            public int[] CreateArray(int size, int max)
            {
                var result = new int[size];
                Random r = new Random();
                for(int i; i<size; i++)
                {
                   result[i] = r.Next(max);
                }
                return result;
            }


            private void buttonCreateArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                size = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxSize.Text);
                max = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMax.Text);

                createArray = CreateArray(size, max);
                orderedArray = array.OrderBy(a => a);
                orderedByDescendingArray = array.OrderByDescending(a => a);        
           }
      }
}
```

//P.S. Code may contain errors coz I typed it directly here.

Comment: i try this but i am getting a red line under `array`.OrderBy and `array`.OrderByDescending(). The error: `does not exist in current context`

Comment: @charliecodex23, add `using System.Linq;` directive to the top of your document.

Answer (score 1):

No need to implement your own algorithm to sort or reverse an array.

Use [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc.aspx) and/or [Array.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx).

To sort in descending order, first sort then reverse the array.

Answer (score 0):

Consder using built methods for sorting like [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx). They have variants that take comaprer to customize sorting.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use logic to create reverse order array. In C# has default method to reverse it. so used that and you can get output ..

```
        string fullOrder= Console.ReadLine();
        char[] charArray= fullOrder.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        Console.WriteLine(charArray);
        Console.ReadLine();
```